# html nested li styles - colored bar in front of each line

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I want to styles a list that I get out of a markdown generation. The generated html code is this:

```css
ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    background: white;
    margin: 4px 0;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-left: 24px;
    border-left: 12px solid #5EAADF;
    background: #F6F8FA;
}

ul {
    padding-inline-start: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1.1
        <ul>
          <li>Item 1.1.1</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Item 1.2
        <ul>
          <li>Item 1.2.1
            <ul>
              <li>Item 1.2.1.1</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

I want to add a colored bar in front of each line. I just managed to style it like this. But what I want to have is this:

[image]

Is there any way this is possible with the generated html code?

Comment: The blue “border” could be emulated via a `::before` pseudo element, but the background is going to be a problem - you can not get easily “eliminate” the light-blue background of “Item 1” before the sub-items. But maybe you can fix that using a gradient that only applies the gray color for an amount of “one line height”, using em units. (But this will fail if any of those list items ever goes beyond one single line.)

Comment: Or an absolute positioned `::after` to simulate the background, but that would still require that you specify the height of that as roughly “one line”, and will fail if the content of an item goes over two ore more lines.

Comment: I see what you are trying. But I can't guarantee that its just one line :/

Comment: Not sure that’s solvable then without wrapping the LI content without the children in an additional element first.

Comment: Yes. That was also my guess too. But I can work with a compromise.

Comment: If you need this with solid background colors only - no transparency, no backgrounds behind the whole thing shining through - then you could perhaps emulate it by putting a white border around the LI - 4px on the top and bottom, and the necessary amount to replace the margin/padding that currently achieve the nested indentation on the left, so that this covers up the background color of the parent LI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with pseudo code.

However, without any HTML changes I don't think you'll get perfection. I would make life a whole lot easier if the text of the `<li>` elements would be wrapped in a `<p>` or `<span>`

```css
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  background: white;
  margin: 4px 0;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-left: 24px;
  background: #F6F8FA;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 20px;
  /* Added */
}

ul li:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  height: 24px; /* line-height + padding-top */
  width: 12px; /* original border width */
  background-color: #5EAADF;
}

ul {
  padding-inline-start: 0;
  /* 
    Experimental technology, limited browser support
    See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-inline-start
  */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1.1
        <ul>
          <li>Item 1.1.1</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Item 1.2
        <ul>
          <li>Item 1.2.1
            <ul>
              <li>Item 1.2.1.1</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is not exactly what I wanted, but it gets pretty close and helps me! Do you think there is a way to also apply that to the light background color? And what about when the list item is two lines long?

Comment: @Visores Without any HTML changes I don't think you'll get perfection. I would make life a whole lot easier if the text of the <li> elements would be wrapped in a <p> or <span>

Comment: Thats true. When you edit your question and mention this in the first sentence then I accept yours as the correct answer :) Thanks!